# How to get only highest score/record in a game's daily leaderboard with Rails 4 + Postgres

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a game with a Rails 4 + Postgres backend on Heroku. Our daily leaderboard shows the highest 100 scores in the game. We have a User model and a Score model (User has_many :scores).

It works as expected like this:

```
class Score < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def self.daily_leaders
    where(['created_at > ? and created_at < ?', Time.now.beginning_of_day, Time.now.end_of_day]).order("points DESC").limit(100)
  end
end
```

But we'd now like to change this so it **only shows the highest score for each user**. I have tried every combination of additional .select() .distinct and .pluck ActiveRecord methods I can, but I'm always getting PG errors.

What would be the proper way to get JUST each user's highest score for just today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Score < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def self.user_max_scores
    where('date(created_at) = ?', Date.today).select('user_id, max(points) as max_points').group(:user_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok, that works but how would I include other columns (like the timestamps)?